# Optimization by order of columns in select clause of SQL statement

Tags: sql

I was asked to optimize a SQL query in one of the interviews I attended. The table `PRODUCTS` structure is like this:

- PRODUCT_NAME - Which has around unique 200 values repeated
- STATE - Which has around 20 unique values repeated
- COUNTRY - Which has around unique 5 values repeated

The table contains 1 million rows. I was given the below SQL statement and was asked to complete it. The SQL is to fetch all the products for a particular state.

```
SELECT _______ 
FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE STATE = 'CALIFORNIA'
```

My answer was below:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, STATE, COUNTRY 
FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE STATE = 'CALIFORNIA'
```

The interviewer was not happy with the answer and later told me that the order of the columns in the select clause could have been used to optimize and I had failed to do it.

So does the order of the columns being used in the select statement have any significant improvement in efficiency of a select query. If so, how?

Comment: I think you should decide if California is a state or country, and which database you are using.  However, the interviewer does not seem to know much about databases, based on that comment.

Comment: My bad, edited the question.

Comment: His explanation was since PRODUCT_NAME has more unique elements than the other two columns, it was right to put it at the end of the select clause making the statement become - SELECT COUNTRY, STATE, PRODUCT_NAME ......

Comment: . . The only thing I can think of is that `state` (and probably `country`) are not needed in the `select` and removing them would reduce the volume of data being returned and improve performance.

Comment: The order of the column in the SELECT list has no influence on the performance of the query. The _number_ of columns might indeed have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot fathom what the interviewer is thinking or what type of database the interviewer is referring to.

Databases store data on data pages, which use a binary format and contain other information (such as null-flags and perhaps record ids and page ids and so on).  Retrieving values for a record requires parsing the data page -- and this takes place regardless of the order of the columns being returned by the query.

Perhaps the confusion is with indexes.  Some databases recommend ordering the columns in a multi-column index based on selectivity (i.e. the number of values).  When all columns in the index are used for equality comparisons, then there might be some slight optimization.  However, the ordering of the columns in indexes is usually influenced by other factors, based on the queries being optimized.

The only optimization I can readily think of is removing columns.  If you know the state, there is no reason to return the state.  And you probably intend for that state to be in the United States, so the country is irrelevant as well.  There might be some optimization to using a constant (`'California' as state`), but it is hard to imagine anyone actually caring about such a nano improvement in performance on a query that reads much of a large table.